# How can I filter variables by a specific type

Tags: r, dataframe

Having the table below as an example, how can I filter only columns that are of type 'chr' ? For example, I would like to see a list of only string variables:
for example :
Timber chr

```
dat <- read.table(text = " Timber apcalc    admit       num
   pine        0        0         7
   pine        0        1         1
   oak         1        0         3
   olive       1        1         7
   olive       0        0         5
   oak         0        1         1
   pine        1        0         0
   pine        1        1         6", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give you a list of character variables (columns) in your dataframe, use:

```
sapply(dat[sapply(dat, is.character)],class)
```

in this case it gives:

```
named list()
```

However this gives not the desired result. With `str(dat)` you get more info about the variables (columns) in your whole dataframe, which gives:

```
'data.frame':   8 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ timber: Factor w/ 3 levels "oak","olive",..: 3 3 1 2 2 1 3 3
 $ apcalc: int  0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
 $ admit : int  0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
 $ num   : int  7 1 3 7 5 1 0 6
```

As you can see there is no character variable in your dataset. When you use:

```
sapply(dat[sapply(dat, is.factor)],class)
```

It gives:

```
  timber 
"factor"
```

Comment: Although this provides useful information, it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, but i'm looking for a solution that will show only chr variables. I tried : sapply(dat[sapply(dat, is.chr)],class) but with no success.

Comment: Got it right this time:
sapply(vipdata_full[sapply(vipdata_full, is.character)],class)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `is.numeric` function combined with `sapply`:

```
dat[sapply(dat, is.numeric)]
  apcalc admit num
1      0     0   7
2      0     1   1
3      1     0   3
4      1     1   7
5      0     0   5
6      0     1   1
7      1     0   0
8      1     1   6
```